# How do I start contributing to GNOME?

Tags: gnome

How do I start contributing to GNOME? I can program in C++ and Python, but have never touched C. I am not familiar with GTK even.

To be honest, I have no idea how GNOME works. All I have is a deep desire to somehow contribute to it.

Where do you recommend do I start? Any tutorial, mailing list or anything. I am ready to do the hard work, I just need a direction.

PS: I could have googled for the problem, but nothing beats the experience I have seen since Google returns SO for most of the questions.

Answer (score 11):

1. Visit [Join GNOME](http://live.gnome.org/JoinGnome).
2. Figure out what you want to do for them
3. If it's development, then:

   1. learn C and GTK
   2. checkout the source code
   3. browse through the bug-tracker to find a reasonably sized task and ask for help of more senior committers to tell you what is at your level
   4. fix it and submit a patch
   5. wait for roses and glory
4. But maybe you can help with other things, as mentioned on [Join GNOME](http://live.gnome.org/JoinGnome)

   1. Translations
   2. Design / Artworks
   3. Technical Documentation (review, proofreading)

Best of luck and thank you for trying to contribute.

Answer (score 5):

Be sure to check out [GNOME Love](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeLove) as well. It's a site aimed at getting people started with GNOME.

Answer (score 2):

You may find it handy and useful by creating new extensions for Gnome shell.
There are a lot of extensions on https://extensions.gnome.org/. It requires JavaScript programming. It will also give you insights of how things work in Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

start simple program with below manual.

[The GTK+ tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/)

[GTK+ 2 Reference Manual](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/index.html)

[GTK+ 3 Reference Manual](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/)

show your program here: http://www.gtkforums.com/ (Project Showcase)

Answer (score -1):

also to note:

you don't have to learn C (even though it's a good idea). You can use PyGtk for GTK development in python (but i won't recommend that because of the speed of python). 
GTK bindings for c++ also exit it's called gtkmm. It have binding for many other librays (Cluttermm, Cairomm, Pangomm).

there are bindings for A LOT of languages but native C is the best solution.

I would recommend learning vala because of it's ease of use but also because of it's speed (but that's just personal preference).

also check the [gnome-devel-demo](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/) out. can be useful

Comment: dismissing a whole GUI framework only because of subjective opinions about the speed of Python, which is more than good enough for any desktop GUI development - lol.